# How do I change th location of Steam games in my Start Menu?

Tags: steam

I find the default "ProgramName" or "CompanyName/ProgramName" scheme of Windows' Start Menu hard to navigate, and always arrange it in a category structure ("Media/Winamp" and such). Unfortunately, Steam does not offer a choice of where to put it in Start Menu, and even if I move it manually to "Games/Steam", newly installed games still appear at "Steam". Moving them every time by hand is a hassle, and probably causes problems at uninstalling as well. Is there a way to override this location in Steam configuration/registry/etc?

Comment: Try this: move the contents of your Steam Start Menu folder into Games/Steam, then make a junction point from Steam to Games/Steam (`mkdir /J "%USERPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Steam" "%USERPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Games\Steam"`); it might clutter your Start Menu a bit, but at least it ought to work.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly (though the command is called `mklink`). After giving the link the hidden attribute, it even disappears from start menu (that needed a restart to take effect, IIRC). Want to answerify it so I can accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a [Junction Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) to trick Steam into creating its shortcuts into `Games\Steam`. Move your current shortcuts into your `Games\Steam` folder, delete the original `Steam` folder, and use the command

> `mklink /J "%USERPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Steam" "%USERPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Games\Steam"`

This way, the shortcuts truly exist in your `Games\Steam` folder. You can then give the hidden attribute to your junction point to stop it from showing in the Start Menu.